# Apache Camel unzip, process and aggregate not completing

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to process a zip file, which contains several files inside (all small, so working in memory is not a problem) that need to be transformed and zipped together again.

I managed to unzip, transform the files, but for some reason, the splitter is not completing, only using `completionTimeout` makes the aggregator to create the final zip archive.

Here's the route:

```
<route id="ZipFile">
    <from uri="file:{{file.path.in}}?move=.done&amp;moveFailed=.error&amp;readLock=rename"/>

    <setProperty propertyName="OriginalZipName">
        <simple>${header.CamelFileName}</simple>
    </setProperty>

    <unmarshal>
        <zipFile usingIterator="true"/>
    </unmarshal>

    <split streaming="true">
        <simple>${body}</simple>

        <log message="************ CamelSplitComplete = ${property.CamelSplitComplete}"/>

        <to uri="direct:ProcessUnzippedFile"/>

        <setHeader headerName="CamelFileName">
            <simple>${property.OriginalZipName}</simple>
        </setHeader>

        <!-- Aggregate to zip -->
        <aggregate strategyRef="zipAggregationStrategy" eagerCheckCompletion="true">
            <correlationExpression>
                <constant>true</constant>
            </correlationExpression>
            <completionPredicate>
                <simple>${property.CamelSplitComplete}</simple>
            </completionPredicate>
            <setHeader headerName="CamelFileName">
                <simple>${property.OriginalZipName}</simple>
            </setHeader>
            <to uri="file://{{file.path.out}}"/>
        </aggregate>
    </split>

</route>
```

Any idea what could be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Camel Splitter provides a built- in aggregator, which makes it even easier to
aggregate split messages back into single outgoing message

You have to define the aggregation strategy in the split definition

```
<split strategyRef="zipAggregationStrategy">
```

Haven't tried it in XML but in Java DSL this is one of my examples that does exactly that.

```
  .unmarshal(zipFile)
                .split(bodyAs(Iterator.class),new ZipAggregationStrategy(true,true))
                .streaming()
                .stopOnException()
                .to("direct:transform-ticket")
                .end();
```

Comment: Hmmm after the split you end up with what? A zip, that only needs a <to uri="file"/> ??

Comment: Yes, actually I return the zip  to an http post request in my case

Comment: I tested it, and there's something I can't get it right... the files in the output zip, are named with the exchange id, instead of the original file names. Any idea if it's possible for the ZipAggregationStrategy to use the CamelFileName ?

Comment: OHHH never mind, I forgot passing the args to the ZipAggregationStrategy! That worked! Awesome!